# Paperclip save image without losing quality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How to save image and don't lose quality?

in my model

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:blog_article_main => "940x400#"}
```

original image
[image]
and after save[image]
it became blurry

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `:quality => 100]` to your `has_attached_file` in the model

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:blog_article_main => ["940x400#", :quality => 100]}
```

Comment: @user do you have any `convert_options`?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
has_attached_file :image, 
                  :styles          => { :blog_article_mai => '940x400#' },
                  :convert_options => { :blog_article_mai => '-quality 80' }
```